# divisor of $(z-1)dz$ on projective space

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question in complex analysis

Let $(z-1)dz$ be 1-form on projective space $\mathbb{CP}^1$,what is the divisor of it?$

---

I want to use the coordinate $\frac{1}{z}$, then I get $(\frac{1}{z}-1)-\frac{1}{z^2}$

Comment: How do you get that?

Comment: You apparently «get $(1/z-1)-1/z^2$»...